# Linear maps and their matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Let $L:V\to V$ be any $F$-linear map. Let $\mathcal{B}_1=\{v_1,v_2,\dots v_n\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2 =\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\}$ be any two bases for $V$. We know that there exists a unique invertible $F$-linear map $T:V\to V$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$ for all $\in\{1,\dots,n\}.$

$Question.$ Let $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_1}$ and $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_2}$ be the matrices of $L$ with respect to the bases $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$, respectively. Is it true that $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_1}$ and $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_2}$ are conjugate by a matrix of $T$?

$Attempt.$ Let $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_1,\mathcal{B}_2}$ be the matrix coming from the coefficients of $L(v_i)$ in terms of $w_j$ for all $i,j$. Then, I got the relations $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_1}=[T\circ L]_{\mathcal{B}_1,\mathcal{B}_2}=[T]_{\mathcal{B}_1}[L]_{\mathcal{B}_1,\mathcal{B}_2}$ and $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_2}=[T^{-1}\circ L]_{\mathcal{B}_2,\mathcal{B}_1}=[T]_{\mathcal{B}_2}^{-1}[L]_{\mathcal{B}_2,\mathcal{B}_1}$. But, I couldn't see any relationship between the matrices $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_1}$ and $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_2}$ in terms of a matrix $T$. Thanks!

Comment: The relations you have are incorrect. Note that $[L]_{B_1}$ needs inputs expressed in terms of $B_1$, and yields outputs expressed in terms of $B_1$. But $[TL]_{B_1,B_2}$ expresses outputs in terms of $B_2$. It cannot possibly equal $[L]_{B_1}$.

Comment: There is only one way to compose these Linear maps which type checks. 

$[L]_{B_1}$ expects things in $B_1$ coordinates and spits them back out in $B_1$ coordinates, if I want to turn it into something that accepts things in $B_2$ coordinates I have to precompose it with something that takes $B_2$ coordinates and turns them into $B_1$ coordinates. Likewise if I want it to spit something out in $B_2$ coordinates I have to compose it with something that takes $B_1$ coordinates and yields something in $B_2$ coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by “$[L]_{\mathcal{B}_1}$ and $[L]_{\mathcal{B}_2}$ are conjugate by a matrix of $T$“?